# How remove first match in gsub?

Tags: ruby, logstash

I have this

```
2016-05-20T13:36:29.835, CTF3D57C
```

and I want this

```
2016-05-2013:36:29.835, CTF3D57C
```

I just want to remove the first `T` character. How do I do this?

Comment: i have a field in logstash with this text

Comment: And if this is a string, then `str = str.sub('T', '')`?

Comment: Just to add to understanding, the `g` in `gsub` means "global," so if you used `gsub`, you'd be replacing both "T" characters in the string. `sub` is the way to go.

Comment: ok i can use ruby like this ruby 
  {
  code => "event['logTime'] = event['logTime'].chop"
  }

Comment: But this dont work ruby 
  {
  code => "event['message'] = event['message'].sub('T', '')"
  }

Comment: Just try: ` { code => event['message'].sub('T', '') }`

Answer (score 1):

This will [substitute](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/sub) the first 'T' in string with anything you want:

```
str = str.sub('T', '')
```

If you wish to substitute all occurrence of any substring or regex, use [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)

Comment: Semantically better would be to use `str.delete!('T')`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: No. That will delete all occurrences of 'T'. @crisx just wants to delete the first occurence. `delete!` is only valid for gsub in this case.

Comment: Oh, indeed, sorry.